# How to enrich HTTP request headers with vertx-http-proxy

Tags: vert.x

With vertx-http-proxy (https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vertx-http-proxy), What is the best way to add/plug our custom authentication mechanism (like an LDAP authentication based on the client cert and populate an Authorization Basic header for our backend target) ?

Answer (score 1):

For the moment you can use directly the ProxyRequest and ProxyResponse which gives control over the flow. When the ProxyResponse is ready to be sent, you can before customize the proxy response HTTP headers.

Comment: The only way I found could be: `vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(HttpProxy.reverseProxy2(vertx.createHttpClient()).selector(request -> {request.headers().set(AUTHORIZATION, "Basic " + retrieveBase64CredentialsFromLdap(request));return Future.succeededFuture(backendSocketAddress);})).listen(rpSocketAddress);`

Is it the right way?

Comment: The syntax can be simplified (though it comes down to the same):
`server.requestHandler(request -> { request.headers().set("Host", hostHeader); proxy.handle(request); });`